# What are some patterns to manage access to Saas features based on subscription level

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, saas

In saas apps, one of the core functionalities is often telling people that have one of several subscription levels (Basic, Gold, Platinum etc.) what features or resources they are able to or not able to access at their current level of subscription.

As I understand it, this is a core part of multitenant architectures. `Is there a course or book that goes over patterns or implementations that solve problems like the one I listed?` Technology is not important, though something for ASP.Net or Rails would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. This question needs to be broken down. However, the logic is as follows,

1. Each tenant has a subscription
2. Each subscription has a collection of features
3. When a tenant or its users login, we get the subscription and based on the features, we allow access to the application.
4. You have to restrict the UI, Api etc based on this tenant subscription based features.

HTH